# How do I shrink my images according to adjusted screen size?

Tags: image, flexbox, tailwind-css, css-position

I've been struggling with getting my images to resize when switching to mobile etc. everything is fine when in desktop mode, images look fine.

However, when I reduce the page size the image distorts as if it is being pushed from either side, just wondering if there is something I could look at or do to fix this?

I've managed thus far but I keep running into the same issue. Cheers!

```js
import React from "react";
import { slides } from "../constants";
import { useState } from "react";
import { FaArrowAltCircleRight, FaArrowAltCircleLeft } from "react-icons/fa";

const Carousel = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length -1 ? 0 : current + 1) 
  }

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length -1 : current -1)
  }

  if(!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0){
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <section className="slider">
      <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide}/>
      <FaArrowAltCircleRight className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
      {slides.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <div className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'} key={index}>
            {index === current && ( <img src={slide.image} alt={slide.alt} className="image"/>)}
          </div>
        )     
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

I've tried inputting flex adjustments, but I'm not sure I'm putting them in the right place, the `index.css` file for this section currently looks like as follows:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  width: relative;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 32px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #57DEE4;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.left-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 32px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #57DEE4;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: `width: relative;` is not a thing.

Comment: yeah my bad, was just playing around